# Bootstrap modal and drop down menu not working in the same nav bar, how do I override CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So here's the code I'm using to create a NAV bar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#myModal" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">Login</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown all-camera-dropdown">  
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">  
            My Account  
               <b class="caret"></b>  
           </a>  
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
            <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">List item</a></li>    
        <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Another item</a></li>
     </ul>  
</li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I added the modal funcationality to my NAV bar first, here's my trigger for the modal window.

```
$('#myModal').on('hide',function(){
    $('.nav > li > a.modal-open-li').removeClass('modal-open-li');
});
```

I then added the drop-down menu. However my modal isn't working now. Are they in the same CSS namespace? How do I override this?

Here are the scripts files that I am using:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/formsAction.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Here's the CSS files I'm using

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I comment the following two scripts my modal starts working but my drop-down menu stops working.

```
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: doesn't matter.. you got my answer? is it working?

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

1)  Use either bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css but not both.

2) If you want override styles from bootstrap, create a `style` file and add it after the bootstrap.css

ie,

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Your custom css file-->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now in your `custom.css` file give `!important` to the styles you're overriding.

**JAVASCRIPT**

1) Use either bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js but not both.

2) `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js` will contain all the javascript functionality.
no need to add the `modal.js`, `dropdown.js`, `datepicker.js` again, so remove it.

Comment: I tried what you just posted and my modal window does not work without modal.js.

Comment: to activate your modal just write     $('#myModal').modal(); what you have written?

Comment: I've specified that in my question, have a look. Meanwhile I'll try what you've posted.

Comment: I tried that. I need the modal window to open on clicking the list item on the NAV bar so I'll stick to using the code that I've written for the modal window.

Comment: I've removed dropdown.js and datepicker.js. It's still either the drop-down menu or the modal window that's working. More importantly, how do I decide which styles to override?

Comment: On the same button you are triggering both modal and dropdown??

Comment: No Login generates the modal and My Account the dropdown.

Comment: Played around with the stuff you posted it's working now. Thanks!